# Unwrapping a Samsung s10 plus

Tags: uv

This is my first post here but not my first issue with Blender. I have always been able to solve these problems by either watching a youtube tutorial or finally figuring it out by myself. But that is not the case today...
I bought a 3D model of a Samsung s10 plus and it looks great! The problem tho is when i (smart) unwrap it, the unwrapping gets weird. Since the edges of this god forsaken phone is rounded in a kind of extreme way i guess Blender gets confused? Believe me, i LOVE blender but this time she has put me on the spot. I just cant figure out how to solve this...
So! heres the problem:

[image]

Here you can see the curved sides

And when i Un-wrap it it looks like this

[image]

So the sides, top and bottom gets their own islands on the side there. And if i try to move those sides in to the image it becomes very weird

[image]

I am in desperate need of help and i hope that someone knows what the problem is. If there is a need for more information in i order to help me i can of course provide it.

Comment: Hello :). Have you considered using manual seams? That will give you *much* better control.

Comment: Hey! I will try that out. Thank you Jachym :)

Comment: I did not work :( The UV editor gives me the same islands and it stil looks like the last picture